# Why is my C++ Class variable unexpectedly changing outside scope?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reverse-Engineer and fix a Win32 Console Application which is throwing an unhandled exception.

I've got 32 instances of a class running in threads. These "Service" threads should each create / delete a unique instance of CMessage regularly and each of these CMessage objects is declared private in the Service class.

When I run the application in the debugger (I'm using Visual Studio 2005) the watch window for the CMessage indicates that right before a CMessage member function is invoked the address of CMessage changes to 0x00000000 - the cause of the exception.

There is no straightforward explanation that i can see for why this happens. Nothing untoward appears to be happening between the previous line of code and this one, so my suspicion is that somehow each thread is mistakenly referencing the CMessage object from one of the other threads in some cases (as at some point during the threads lifetime the CMessage object for that thread is deleted).

My question is: What is the best way to make sure that these CMessage objects are absoloutely thread safe and can't be modified / deleted from anywhere, except for the current class scope? I thought that this was what private was for, but I'm not entirely sure now. One thing I thought about doing was referring to the CMessage object as follows:

```
this->myCMessage;
```

as opposed to just:

```
myCMessage;
```

Would this make any difference?

Comment: No. More likely is that you are calling some function which is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the private tag in class is just a syntactic sugar, it won't change how the code is generated.

If you're calling a member function and right after that the class member goes to NULL, the problem might be that the member function somehow deletes the CMessage object. Note though, that if the CMessage object is allocated in stack, the problem probably is not that case.

Another problem might be that the CService object gets destroyed(thread gets terminated) before it completes the current function accessing the CMessage object.

Comment: Yes, it turns out there was another thread outside of this function messing with the pointer indirectly. The address held by the pointer was being stored out elsewhere to a vector, the contents of which was being periodically purged.

Thanks for your help :)